# connecting firebase Realtime database with chrome extension

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension

I'm beginner and I'm developing a chrome extension that shows data received from my firebase realtime database. It does not need Login, or any personal information.
I'm trying to use REST API. Until now I have been in a test mode so I opened access to data for all. But Google keeps mailing me that I have to change the access rule because it is dangerous.

My present access rule is this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Now, I fetch data from `https://<project name>.firebaseio.com/<database name>.json`. But if I change the rule, the access will be denied.

So I want to add some key to the url and change access rule according to it so that I can fetch data from the url. For example,
`https://<project name>.firebaseio.com/<database name>.json?some_key=<some_key>`.
I do not need personal keys so I want only one key just like when we get information from open APIs. For example, when I use weather api, I get my api key from the host and adds the key to url.

Is this possible? If it is, I wonder two things.

1. the key that I can use (for example, realtime base wep API key)
2. access rule of realtime database

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example code for reading data off of a realtime database using a chrome extension? This is something I have been working on for a while and since there isn't a lot of information out there this would really help me. Also is it Manfiest 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass parameters to the Firebase database like this:

```
https://<project name>.firebaseio.com/<database name>.json?some_key=<some_key>
```

But if you change the order of the values, it suddenly becomes possible:

```
https://<project name>.firebaseio.com/<some_key>/<database name>.json
```

We then change the security rules to only allow access when somebody already knows the secret key:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    "$some_key": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

Now the secret key is part of the path of the data, and only a user that already knows the key can read the data for that key.